# Finding the exterior derivative of a k-form in the 4th dimension

Tags: math, calculus

I have learned how to find the exterior derivative of 1-forms and 2-forms in the 2nd and 3rd dimensions (2 and 3 variables) but now I want to do the same in the 4th dimension (4 variables) except I'm not sure how and can't find any tutorials online.

Here is an example:

Let A(x,y,z,w)=(4zw)dy^dw

How would I find this 2-form's exterior derivative ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Try [math.se].

Comment: ...apart from agreeing with @NicoSchertler. Just look at the definition: if f = g dx ^ dy then df = dg ^ dx ^ dy and for dg is straight forward... with all final dx ^ dx = 0 etc.